# Not able to access API endpoints and swagger URL when asyncio.run() used in main

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

not able to access the swagger endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs when using asyncio.run(startup()) in **main** but background tasks start running in the background.

```
app = FastAPI()

monitor_data = [
    {"url": "https://endpoint_1/", "type": "https", "Interval": 30},
    {"url": "https://endpoint_2/", "type": "https", "Interval": 60}
]

@app.get('/')
async def amialive():
    return "Live"

async def monitor(url, interval):
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        print(f"{url}: {response.status_code})")
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)

async def startup():
    tasks = []
    for data in monitor_data:
        url = data["url"]
        interval = data["Interval"]
        task = asyncio.create_task(monitor(url, interval))
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(startup())
    # asyncio.create_task(startup()) 
    uvicorn.run("network_monitoring:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000 ,reload=True)
```

And when I remove asyncio.run(startup()) from the **main**, able to access the API endpoint as well as swagger.

is there a way where I can run the background tasks on the startup of the script and use the endpoint as well at the same time? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `startup` awaits `monitor`, which is an infinite loop, which means `asyncio.run(startup())` will block and run forever.

To remove the blocking behavior, simply remove `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` at the end of `monitor`. Since its purpose is to create background tasks, and `asyncio.create_task` does that, it's not needed.

However, that's not enough. When calling `uvicorn.run`, that will start a new event loop (even a new process), and you want to run your background tasks in the same event loop. To do this, you can use [FastAPI's startup event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event): add the startup decorator `@app.on_event("startup")` to your `startup` function

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("network_monitoring:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```